# Double sum $\sum_{i=1}^3 (\sum_{j=1}^i(\frac{i}{j}))$

Tags: calculus, summation

Could anyone help me with this please:

$\sum_{i=1}^3 (\sum_{j=1}^i(\frac{i}{j}))$

I should use the fact that $\sum_{j=1}^1(j)=\frac{i(i+1)}{2}$ but I am not sure how.

Comment: There are only six terms in the sum.  Surely you can do this manually if you have to.

Comment: Those six terms in the sum corresponding to the following $(i,j)$ pairs:  $(1,1),(2,1),(2,2),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3)$

Comment: @JMoravitz Yeah, i did it manually and got 9.5, but wanted to know if there is a more eloquent wat to simplify it.

Comment: "*I should use the fact that $\sum\limits_{j=1}^i (j) = \frac{i(i+1)}{2}$*"  no, this has nothing to do with this problem since $j$ is in the denominator, not the numerator here.  Just add the six numbers together and be done.  Worry about generalizations like this when the number of terms being added is too large to handle.

Comment: @JMoravitz Great! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

Okay, so you got the answer $9.5$ manually, but you want something more.  Let's define $$
a_n = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^i \frac{i}{j}.
$$
How do we find a formula for $a_n$ in general?  The first thing we can do is observe that $$
a_n = \sum_{i=1}^n i H_i,\;\text{where}\;H_i = \sum_{j=1}^i \frac{1}{j}
$$ is the $i^\text{th}$ Harmonic number.  How can we simplify this further?  Hmm.  Let's write a little code to compute some values -- rational values, not numerical ones -- and look for a pattern.  $$
a_1 = 1,\;a_2 = 4,\;a_3 = \frac{19}{2},\;a_4 = \frac{107}{6},\;a_5 = \frac{117}{4},\;\text{etc.}
$$
No pattern leaps out.  However, there is a great resource for recognizing sequences of numbers:
[OEIS](https://oeis.org), the On-line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences.  Because $a_n$ involves sums that have the numbers $1$ through $n$ in the denominator, $n! a_n$ is an integer.  Alternatively, we can just guess that multiplying the sequence by $n!$ will yield an integer sequence by looking at the denominators of $a_n$ for $n = 1$ to $20$.  For example the denominator of $a_{20}$ is $369512 = 2^3 \times 11 \times 13 \times 17 \times 19$.  This is begging to be cancelled out by a factor of $19!$ or $20!$.  The first few terms of $n! a_n$ are $1$, $8$, $57$, $428$, $3510$.  Searching for this in OEIS yields the sequence [A307642](https://oeis.org/A307642).  From the information there, we find that $$
a_n = \frac{n(n+1)}{4}\left(2 H_{n+1} - 1\right).
$$
Finally, how do we prove this?  We can verify that the formula satisfies $a_1 = 1$ and $a_n - a_{n-1} = nH_n$, which yields a proof by induction.

**Edit:**  It occurs to me that a nice way to derive the formula for $a_n$, rather than finding it via OEIS and then proving it by induction, is to use summation by parts.  The motivation for this is that $H_i \approx \log i$ and if we were integrating $x \log x$ we'd use integration by parts, so presumably there's an analogous technique called summation by parts.  And yes, there is:  it's also called Abel transformation.  To make it look like integration by parts, let's write it as$$
\begin{align}
u_n &= H_n, & v_{n+1}-v_n &= n,\\
u_{n+1}-u_n &= 1/(n+1), & v_{n+1} &= n(n+1)/2.
\end{align}
$$
The [summation by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts) formula is $$
a_n = \sum_{i=1}^n u_i(v_{i+1}-v_i) = (u_n v_{n+1} - u_1 v_1) - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} v_{i+1} (u_{i+1}-u_i).
$$
Therefore $$
a_n = H_n \frac{n(n+1)}{2} - 0 - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{i(i+1)}{2}\frac{1}{i+1},
$$
which simplifies to the formula above for $a_n$.

Finally, to answer the original question explicitly, the formula for $a_n$ yields $$
a_3 = \frac{3(3+1)}{4}\left(2 H_4 - 1\right), \;\text{where} \; H_4 = 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} = \frac{25}{12},
$$
so
$$
a_3 = 3 \cdot \frac{19}{6} = \frac{19}{2}.
$$

Comment: In the definition of $H_i$ it should be $j$ in the denominator instead of $i$.

Comment: What a nice and readable answer

Comment: Thank you stange.  Fixed.